Cisco control and management plane interfaces
What is the command to display information about the management plane interface?

Your question is quite broad, but there is the show control-plane [aggregate|cef-exception|counters|features|host|transit] command. There are also commands such as the show policy-map control-plane command to show control plane policing.
